# check if a jsonb field contains an array

Tags: type-inference, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` field in a PostgreSQL table which was supposed to contain a dictionary like data aka {} but few of its entries got an array due to source data issues.

I want to weed out those entries. One of the ways is to perform following query -

```
select json_field from data_table where cast(json_field as text) like '[%]'
```

But this requires converting each jsonb field into text. With data_table having order of 200 million entries, this looks like bit of an overkill.

I investigated `pg_typeof` but it returns jsonb which doesn't help differentiate between a dictionary and an array.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `json_typeof` function?

```
select json_field from data_table where json_typeof(json_field) = 'array'
```

Comment: it says `function json_typeof(jsonb) doesn't exists`